# After I upgraded the site, some admin pages get a "Field storage definition for 'uuid' could not be found." error

Tags: 9, upgrading

Upgrading Drupal 8 to Drupal 9 went smooth and without any issues, but now when I visit admin/reports/status or admin/modules/uninstall, I get this exception.

> Drupal\Core\Field\FieldException: Field storage definition for 'uuid' could not be found. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorageSchema->getEntitySchema() (line 968 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php).

Searching for the error gives a few results of the same issue, but without solution. I've ran database updates (nothing pending), cleared caches, and tried to disable various contributed modules without success.

Comment: Pasting in the text of an error is always more helpful than a screenshot unless it is a UI error.

Answer (score 1):

> I've ran database updates (nothing pending), cleared caches and tried
> disabling a various contrib modules without success.

A systematic approach would be to find out the entity type and with this information the module which is causing the error.

Change the code line throwing the exception to include the entity type ID:

*(line 971 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorageSchema.php):*

```
throw new FieldException("Field storage definition for '$field_name' in '$entity_type_id' could not be found.");
```

If you don't need the entity data or you are able to restore it, then uninstall the module before you upgrade Drupal and reinstall it later. If this is not an option you have to check the issue queue for a fix in the database update hooks of the module.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to track down the issue. The previous admin had installed some core test modules (enity_test) that were corrupt. Forcing removing the module resolved the issue.

Comment: My answer is more about the error message in general. This is more suitable for DA because those who search for this error message might have the problem with a different module.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to track down the issue. The previous admin had installed some core test modules (enity_test) that were corrupt. Forcing removing the module resolved the issue.